# Power strip with individual time delays for each socket

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, delay, sequential-logic

I am to purchase a power strip that has programmable time delays for each socket. What I would like to happen is once the power strip receives power, the first socket from the strip counts down from 2 minutes. Once it reaches zero, the socket turns on and power is sent to the connected device. The same process then occurs for the second socket on the power strip where this time I would like it to turn on 4 minutes after it receives power.

Once the timers have counted down to zero I would like them to supply power to the sockets and connected devices continuously. The timers should only restart if the power supplying the power strip is turned off and on again.

I need this type of programmable power strip for a remote device that experiences frequent power surges. Each time the power is cut out from the device I need it to reestablish internet connection before the other components turn on.

Comment: So what is your question, bearing in mind that shopping questions are not allowed? What is your budget if you have to build it yourself?

Comment: You are allowed however to ask if something exists and what its name is.  In this case the answer would appear to be a "Power Sequencer" and there does not appear to be a cheap "power strip" version.  As an alternative, you could likely build your own with time delay relays.  Better figure out what you want to ask about!

Comment: You should also add to your question how many channels you need and how many sockets on each.

Comment: Good luck with your supplier. Got specs ?(ha) what no network retry fix on power up? What about a UPS?

Comment: I do not know the specs off hand but it is nothing high voltage. Also, I am not asking for a specific model to buy just if something like this exists. A device with 6 output would be ideal and I know audio equipment uses power sequencers but I am would like something programmable where I can set the delay on start up.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Outlet-Power-Sequencer-Conditioner-Controller/dp/B07P76C2PF

Comment: Building my own is an option in the future, but if I there is a plug and play option then that would be ideal for now.

Comment: If you go with a power sequencer, two things it appears you'll have to watch for is making sure the programmable time is sufficiently long, and making sure the unit has memory and can sequence on power up (as opposed to beginning the sequence on a signal when already powered up).  Depending on the duration and nature of your "surges" and how often you can do maintenance, you really should consider a power conditioner and/or UPS.  Power conditioners are for surges and aberrations that don't necessarily interrupt power and UPS units are for interruptions in power and may include a conditioner.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a **power sequencer**.
There are many brands that make them:
Panamax, Furman, Pyle...